# I can't Vertex Paint draw but I can Vertex Paint fill (Set Vertex Colours),

Tags: vertices, color

After UV unwrapping, I tried to vertex paint. However, I don't know if I might turn on ( or off) something accidentally that makes me can't Vertex Paint draw at all. I followed basic tutorials and can easily draw on a new blender file but I couldn't draw on the file I'm having troubles with. I can still Set Vertex Colours. I also noticed that my brush size ring has a white colour. Please give me suggestions on how to fix the issue.

Comment: Could you upload your screenshot with Vertex Paint mode and Vertex Colors panel on right? Please consider upload your blend file so we can see your issue clearly.

Comment: @TergTurry thank you. here's the blender file i"m working on: https://pasteall.org/blend/128ba0b8498345c2ab4e3733cb454931

Comment: You forgot to remove Texture.002 on your brush setting.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you explain why such a thing affects the vertex paint?

Comment: Texture.002 is completely black so it paint nothing.